# App security on iOS and android platforms

Tags: ios

I would just like to ask a question about app security. I want to understand the different layers of app security on iOS and android platforms if I were to create a in-house app which is only available to my office.

What are the potential risks I might face in terms of exposed information or cyber threats?

Comment: Hi.  Unfortunately your question is too broad.  We don't know what information you have in or access from your app.  In general you have to assume that any information that you store *on the device* can be accessed and/or copied by the device owner.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re an app developer, AppSec analyst, or QA specialist, chances are you’ve heard the term OWASP Mobile Top 10 thrown around in conversation before. Nearly all mobile app security testing services check against OWASP safety standards, and it is widely considered the gold standard in-app security. http://blog.appscanonline.com/2018/09/25/get-to-know-owasps-mobile-top-10/